# Use date time control that blackberry device uses

Tags: blackberry, java-me

In Blackberry device if we go to

Options ---> Date/Time ---->Use Network Time --> No

Now when we select date or time a very stylish selector opens up that
enables user to set date and time.

Can i use such control in my app.

I saw such in Storm 9530

Any idea please help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have seen in 5.0 os, its [DateTimePicker](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/picker/DateTimePicker.html).

even if you use old DateField, it will look different in different os.

Answer (score 0):

That is the net.rim.device.api.ui.component.DateField that is included in OS version 5.0 (and since you saw it on a Store a assume also 4.7). Previous OS versions use the older UI element. So I guess your answer is it depends on the OS version your program will be installed on.

Comment: I think you mean DateTimePicker and it's only available in 5.0 OS.  The 5.0 OS has been released by Verizon on their older Storm 9530 models as well as the newer Storm.